# Is it possible to get the user data folder without creating an instance of the WebView2 browser control?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, webview2

This is how WebView2 sample lets us get the user data folder:

```
auto environment7 = m_webViewEnvironment.try_query<ICoreWebView2Environment7>();
CHECK_FEATURE_RETURN(environment7);
wil::unique_cotaskmem_string userDataFolder;
environment7->get_UserDataFolder(&userDataFolder);
```

But, is it possible to get the **user data folder** without creating an instance of the browser control?

I know you can do this with the SDK / Runtime values:

```
std::wstring CWebBrowser::GetRuntimeVersion()
{
    wil::unique_cotaskmem_string runtimeVersion;
    GetAvailableCoreWebView2BrowserVersionString(nullptr, &runtimeVersion);
    return runtimeVersion.get();
}


std::wstring CWebBrowser::GetSdkBuild()
{
    auto options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
    wil::unique_cotaskmem_string targetVersion;
    CHECK_FAILURE(options->get_TargetCompatibleBrowserVersion(&targetVersion));

    // The full version string A.B.C.D
    const wchar_t* targetVersionMajorAndRest = targetVersion.get();
    // Should now be .B.C.D
    const wchar_t* targetVersionMinorAndRest = wcschr(targetVersionMajorAndRest, L'.');
    CHECK_FAILURE((targetVersionMinorAndRest != nullptr && *targetVersionMinorAndRest == L'.') ? S_OK : E_UNEXPECTED);

    // Should now be .C.D
    const wchar_t* targetVersionBuildAndRest = wcschr(targetVersionMinorAndRest + 1, L'.');
    CHECK_FAILURE((targetVersionBuildAndRest != nullptr && *targetVersionBuildAndRest == L'.') ? S_OK : E_UNEXPECTED);

    // Return + 1 to skip the first . so just C.D
    return targetVersionBuildAndRest + 1;
}
```

I would also like to get the **runtime path** without creating a browser instance (if possible).

Comment: AFAIK, there is no other API to get the path of the User Data Folder.  It is part of the environment of the browser control, so you have to create the environment object to query it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/user-data-folder

Comment: @RemyLebeau Alright. Technically I know this location in my app anyway. But my concern is if WV2 ever change the name of the folder. If not, then I can directly build it. But what about the runtime path?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Looks like I need environment2 to get the runtime path. So can't do what I want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Added my request here: https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/4454